# ¿Cómo ver errores de archivo PHP que se ejecuta en segundo plano?

Tags: php

Tengo un archivo PHP grande que he pasado previamente por un validador de sintaxis, me sale que no tiene errores.

Estoy convencido de que sí tiene alguno en algún lado ya que el código no termina de ejecutarse correctamente.

El caso es que dicho archivo lo tengo subido a mi hosting web (en el FTP), y es llamado por otra web y se ejecuta ahí en mi servidor completamente en segundo plano, es decir, no puedo abrir el enlace directo al archivo php y ver los errores de ejecución que tiene.

¿Hay alguna manera de logearlos y que los pueda leer posteriormente?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿No tienes acceso FTP a tu hosting? allí podrás ver tu archivo PHP y también el errorlog. También puedes ver los errores por cPanel. Pero vía SFTP es mucho mejor que FTP o cPanel.

Comment: Hola @A.Cedano , lo tengo subido al FTP. El caso es que si abro el path del archivo en mi navegador no me sirve de nada (me sale una pantalla en blanco), ya que el archivo sólo se ejecuta correctamente al interactuar en segundo plano con Paypal. Necesitaría que lo que yo no puedo ver en ese momento en pantalla se loguee en un archivo de texto o algo así para luego poder leerlo y corregir los fallos. Qué es eso del errorlog que comentas?

Comment: Me refiero a abrir tu archivo por SFTP, es como ver los archivos de tu máquina local, pero son tus archivos remotos, entre ellos tus archivos PHP y un archivo que se llama error_log que se guarda en cada carpeta donde tenemos archivos PHP. Ese archivo registra todos los errores (a no ser que tengas la notificación de errores apagada). Tu hosting debe tener en la ayuda explicaciones sobre como conectarte via FTP, pues necesitas un programa para ello. Eso sí maneja los archivos con mucho cuidado, si modificas algo debes saber lo que estás haciendo, pues el acceso FTP es delicado.

Comment: ¿Tienes acceso al log de apache en el servidor? Cualquier error de ejecución (estos no te los mostraría un validador de sintasis) debería mostrarse ahí con una configuración php estándar.

Comment: @Muriano, acabo de mirarlo. 1and1 no te deja acceder a los logs de Apache. :(

Comment: @A.Cedano No hay un error_log por ninguna parte. ¿Quizá se pueda crear un script que me cree un archivo con los logs y meter el script por `include()` a mi archivo php principal?

Comment: Ay noooo. Si he entendido bien tu PHP está alojado en un hosting ¿no? Si es así y la notificación de errores no está apagada, debe haber un error_log en alguna parte. Si haces un include lo que harías sería presentar los mensajes de error en pantalla cuando se acceda a ese archivo PHP. **No me refiero al error_log de apache, sino de PHP**.

Comment: Uf sí, acabo de verlo [aquí](https://ayuda.1and1.es/hosting-c85122/scripting-y-programacion-c64780/php-c64788/logs-de-error-de-php-a694887.html), si estás en 1&1, **no te dejan acceder a los archivos log**, no sabía que 1&1 era tan mediocre en ese sentido. Tendrás que hacerlo como explican ellos ahí. O cambiarte de hosting :) Yo uso Bluehost y he usado otros, y **todos** crean los archivos de error_log por defecto. Aunque también dicen [esto](https://help.1and1.com/hosting-c37630/scripts-and-programming-languages-c85099/php-c37728/enable-error-logs-a792503.html) estos de 1&1 confunden.

Answer (score 1):

Si en algún momento este archivo te generó un error, este se guardara en el `error_log` este archivo se guarda en el directorio en el que esta `.php` que ejecutes.

Si no es opción ver el `error_log`, yo utilizo Sublime_Linter para probar los errores que contiene mi archivo justo cuando lo estoy escribiendo antes de subirlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedes ver este me indica que hay un error en la `linea 7` o cerca de ella y es ahí donde entro yo a hacer los cambios pertinentes.

Espero te haya servido esta información.

Comment: error_log no tiene por qué guadarse en la misma carpeta donde está el .php, de hecho y por lo general, ningún entorno de producción guarda el log en la misma carpeta. Depende de la configuración del servidor.

Comment: @Muriano el OP ha indicado que tiene sus archivos en un hosting y por lo general en los hosting se crea un error_log por carpeta y en dicho error_log se registran todos los errores de los archivos PHP de esa carpeta. Así funcionan al menos Bluehost, Hostgator y supongo que casi todos.

Comment: La mayoria de los hosting guardan este archivo error_log en la misma carpeta donde se encuentra el archivo q presenta el error, por lo menos en los casos en los que yo le he usado